# AWS MediaLive channel tries to download old segments from live HLS input

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-live-streaming, aws-media-live

When a MediaLive channel is configured to pull from a live HLS input, the channel pauses download of newer segments while it tries to go back and download older segments. Is there a MediaLive setting to make the channel input forget about old segments that are no longer in the current revision of the playlist?

The retry count and retry interval settings in the channel input network HLS settings only apply to the playlist manifest, not segments, and MediaLive doesn't respect 410 gone. The channel will keep retrying the segment download request.

VLC, OBS, HLS.js, and other video clients are able to consume and play the HLS playlist without any problems.

```
GET      "/hls/live/index.m3u8"
GET      "/hls/live/segment/237/file.ts"
GET      "/hls/live/segment/240/file.ts"
GET      "/hls/live/segment/239/file.ts"
GET      "/hls/live/segment/241/file.ts"
GET      "/hls/live/segment/238/file.ts"
GET      "/hls/live/segment/242/file.ts"
GET      "/hls/live/index.m3u8"

GET      "/hls/live/segment/236/file.ts" |
GET      "/hls/live/segment/236/file.ts" |
...                                      |- 20 times
GET      "/hls/live/segment/236/file.ts" |
GET      "/hls/live/segment/236/file.ts" |

GET      "/hls/live/segment/243/file.ts" |- 20 seconds later, 243 is already gone
GET      "/hls/live/segment/243/file.ts" |
...                                      |- 20 times
GET      "/hls/live/segment/243/file.ts" |
GET      "/hls/live/segment/243/file.ts" |

GET      "/hls/live/segment/244/file.ts" |- 40 seconds later, 244 is already gone
GET      "/hls/live/segment/244/file.ts" |
...                                      |- 20 times
GET      "/hls/live/segment/244/file.ts" |
GET      "/hls/live/segment/244/file.ts" |
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65024415/aws-medialive-and-unreliable-hls-stream has details about retry settings for the HLS manifest.

Answer (score 1):

The retry count and retry interval apply to both manifest and segments, you can lower the number of retries to avoid this.  Also what is your current buffer segments setting set to?

Zach